# How to turn columns into rows in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if you can help. I have a table of staff names along with their sales By month as follows

```
Name            |  surname   | local    | Jan   |  Feb    
————————————————+———    
John.           | Bushill    | Exeter   | 18,500 | 20,100    
Richard         | Niels.     | Plymouth | 21,500 | 19,000    
Emily           | winter     | London   | 30,000 | 21,000
```

I would like to create an sql query that would ouptput the table as rows instead of columns as follows

```
Name.            |  Sales tot    
—————————————————+——    
John Bushill.    | 38,600    
Richard Niels.   | 40,500    
Emily winter.    | 51,000
```

I am using mysql and I understand I could use a case statement but what if the number of months can vary also the months may have the year too.

Sorry if this is a bit of s noob question but I am pretty new to programming.

Thanks in advance for any help. Sam

Comment: It were just a SUM/GROUP BY if you had the DB normalised and not a column for each month separately.

Comment: Your starting point seems to be the end point of another process (aggregation by month perhaps) Do you have source data for this process you can use as your start point or must you use the aggregated data as your start point?

Comment: First normalise your schema. Staff and sales should be in separate tables. The sales table would have three columns: employee_id,yearmonth,sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use sales by month as your start point you could build a query from information_schema.columns and execute a prepared statement.

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (Name            varchar(20),  surname varchar(20),  local varchar(20), Jan int,  Feb int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values
    -> ('John.'           , 'Bushill'    , 'Exeter'   , 18500 , 20100),
    -> ('Richard'         , 'Niels.'     , 'Plymouth' , 21500 , 19000) ,
    -> ('Emily'           , 'winter'     , 'London'   , 30000 , 21000)
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> set @sql =(select
    ->  concat('select concat(name,surname), ',
    -> group_concat(concat('ifnull(',column_name,',0)') SEPARATOR '+'),
    -> ' as total from ', table_name ,';'
    -> )
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox' and ordinal_position > 3
    -> order by ordinal_position
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [sandbox]> execute sqlstmt;
+----------------------+-------+
| concat(name,surname) | total |
+----------------------+-------+
| John.Bushill         | 38600 |
| RichardNiels.        | 40500 |
| Emilywinter          | 51000 |
+----------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> #Simulate new column added
MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table t
    -> add column mar int;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.37 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> update t set mar = 30 where name = 'john.';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> update t set mar = 10 where name = 'richard';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> set @sql =(select
    ->  concat('select concat(name,surname), ',
    -> group_concat(concat('ifnull(',column_name,',0)') SEPARATOR '+'),
    -> ' as total from ', table_name ,';'
    -> )
    -> from information_schema.columns
    -> where table_name = 't' and table_schema = 'sandbox' and ordinal_position > 3
    -> order by ordinal_position
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [sandbox]> execute sqlstmt;
+----------------------+-------+
| concat(name,surname) | total |
+----------------------+-------+
| John.Bushill         | 38630 |
| RichardNiels.        | 40510 |
| Emilywinter          | 51000 |
+----------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this sql got the job done, I had to alter it slightly to pull in other fields but this really helped me to figure it out. Thank you for your hard work, I really learnt from this so I appretiate your time on this and to everyone who took the time to answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by simply [calculating](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html) / using [MySQL String-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) with the data in the field selection of the `SELECT` clasue:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(table.name, ' ', table.surname) as Name,
    table.Jan + table.Feb as 'Sales lot'
FROM
    table;
```

Comment: I don't like this answer, because I consider the premise of the question to be flawed. Nevertheless, it does seem to properly address that premise, so I cannot see why it would be downvoted. Accordingly I have upvoted in order to re-balance world karma.

Comment: @Strawberry maybe it was downvoted to discourage the user from answering bad questions, instead of flagging them for closure.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name,' ',surname) as Name,jan+feb as sales_tot FROM `tbl_monthly` group by name
```

**Output:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya7eV.png

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT does nothing here.

Comment: hello, without group_concat how can you merge two or more columns here?

Comment: what is diff btwn groupconcat and concat?

Comment: The manual covers all of this in considerable detail. I'm not sure that I could add anything to that.